# What WTForm field do you use in flask when you want to enter a list/tuple into a form?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to enter things like (0,1,0) into a wtform as my function requires a list entry for one of the parameters, how do i define this field? I tried stringfield then coverting it to a list in the function but this wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried FieldList.
Here is the description and usage of FieldList in wtforms docs.
https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.1/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList

Hope it Helps.